# Symfony2 Default Select Radio Button

Tags: forms, symfony, radio-button, default, selected

I know there are quite a few posts in various forums in the web on this topic already.
However non of the solutions actually worked for me, although the issue seems quite simple.

I want to pre select a radio button im my symfony2 form:

My entity:

```
namespace Helloworld\CoreBundle\Entity;

class User {
   ...

   /**
    * @var string
    *
    * @ORM\Column(name="gender", type="string", length=6)
    * @Assert\Choice(choices = {"male","female"}, multiple = false, message = "You must choose a valid gender.")
    */
   protected gender;

   ...
}
```

(Getters and setters are there)

My php code:

```
$user = new User();
$user->setGender('male');

$form = $this->createFormBuilder($user)
    ->add('gender', 'choice', array(
        'choices' => array(
          'male' => 'Male',
          'female' => 'Female'
        ),
        'multiple' => false,
        'expanded' => true,
        'required' => true,
    ))
    ->getForm();
```

Now, unfortunately, no radio button is selected by default!

Can anybody help?
Please?

Comment: I use for example male 'data' => '1', right above 'choices'. Is it that what you want? Or ask for the id and set it iin 'data' = $id.

Comment: Arn't you missing a opening-quote just before "choices"?

Answer (score 3):

if you want to preselect button in form please try to use 'data' property with desired key from choice array, like:

```
->add('gender', 'choice', array(
        'choices' => array(
          'male' => 'Male',
          'female' => 'Female'
        ),
        'multiple' => false,
        'expanded' => true,
        'required' => true,
        'data'     => 'male'
    ))
```

Answer (score 1):

I think you need to persist (and/or flush ?) your entity before creating your form, so the entity has an ID etc.
(It's an awful way to pre select the radio button btw)

Answer (score 0):

For those who are still looking for the solution. I was able to solve this problem simply setting a default value for the `$gender` variable:

```
class User {
   ...

   /**
    * @var string
    *
    * @ORM\Column(name="gender", type="string", length=6)
    * @Assert\Choice(choices = {"male","female"}, multiple = false, message = "You must choose a valid gender.")
    */
   protected gender = "male";

   ...
}
```

Answer (score -1):

It seems very logical to me that the radio button having value '`male`' will be selected since your entity already has 'male' as gender. That's the intended behavior from `symfony2` framework.

If you dont want that the radio button does not get selected by default simply don't set gender to the entity before passing it to the form builder.

```
$user = new User();
$user->setGender('male'); //<- remove this line

$form = $this->createFormBuilder($user)
    ->add('gender', 'choice', array(
        'choices' => array(
          'male' => 'Male',
          'female' => 'Female'
        ),
        'multiple' => false,
        'expanded' => true,
        'required' => true,
    ))
    ->getForm();
```